# Matplotlib set facecolor of a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been able to change the facecolor of a plot using basic colors, r,g,b etc. However, I am working on a project and I need to prepare a presentation that will be visually pleasing and I would like to use a wider range of colors, such as colors that are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408237/named-colors-in-matplotlib). This is the code I am using (I want the area below the graph to be colored):

```
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(30, 50))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(x, y, 'k-')
ax1.fill_between(x, min(y), y, facecolor='#8B0000')
```

However, facecolor does nothing when I use HEX colors, but it works when I use 'r','b' etc. Is there any way to use HEX color codes for fill_between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=fill_between#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between) `facecolor` accepts matplotlib color arg or sequence of rgba tuples. If you want to use hex colors you must first convert the hex value to correct format. Take a look at the `matplotlib.colors` module. I'm not fully familiar with the library but maybe [hex2color](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.hex2color) is of use.

Comment: [Visualization of named colors](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html)

Comment: Actually, this is not working. Even when I use converted hex, the color doesn't change. When I use hex for setting font color or anything else, it works fine, but doesn't work for facecolor.

Comment: it seems that something else is going in my code since this worked when I used it with a random plot